# How to transform a fraction into the integer that is in the denominator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Suppose I have a function that has transformed a sequence of integers like so:

$$
f(n) = \log_{10}\frac{1}{n}
$$

I then want to convert those numbers back to $n$. I understand that I first must take $10^{1/n}$ to get rid of my $\log_{10}$ transformation. But how do I go from $1/n$ to just $n$?

For example, let $n = 2$. Then

$$
f(2) = \log_{10}\frac{1}{2} = -0.30103
$$

I can then apply an exponent such that

$$
10^{-0.30103} = \ \sim.5
$$

What do I need to do to transform $.5$ to $2$? Obviously I can multiply $.5$ by $4$, but I need to be able to do this for any given $n$.

I feel like this is something simple I learned in 8th grade, but I'm having a major relapse of memory at the moment.

Comment: $\log_{10}\dfrac1n=-\log_{10}n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y = \log_{10}\frac1n$$

$$10^y = \frac1n$$

$$n = \frac1{10^y}=10^{-y}$$

We have $\frac1{1/2}=2$ in particular.